# Export and Import trained neural net

Tags: export, import, neural-networks

I have trained a neural network and would like to save it to disk. I am using Wolfram version 12.1.1.0 on Windows (64-bit). I have entered the following commands:

```
Export["file1.json", trainedNet, "MXNet"]
```

Two files are created: file1.json and file1.params

When I try to import the file,

```
net = Import["file1.json", "MXNet"]
```

I get the following error message: Layer named "1.1$0" couldn't be created, layer type cast is not supported.

When I use the command,

```
Export["file1.onnx", trainedNet]
```

I get the error message: cannot infer the form of the file file1.onnx

I appreciate any help in resolving the above issues. Thanks and best regards

Chris

Comment: Do you only want to export/import from Mathematica or use the net externally? If the former, perhaps see if `Export["test.wlnet", trainedNet, "WLNet"]` works for you? Although `Export["test.onnx", trainedNet, "ONNX"]` works for me in 12.2.0 for Linux too..

Comment: The WLNet option works for me, but the ONNX option still does not work. For now, I plan to use it within Mathematica, but eventually I would like to use the net externally. Thank you for your help. - Chris